# How can I send a list through an Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, list, flask

I am trying to use an ajax call from my html to retrive locations for an embeded map. I want to send a list instead of a dictionary to my call. How can I do that?

This is my ajax (home.html) call code:

```
var locName = []
          $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
              type : 'POST',
              url : "{{url_for('main.process')}}",
              success : function(resp){
                  locName = resp.data
                  document.getElementById('legend').innerHTML = locName;
                  // I am using this to make see what the call data is 
                }
              })
          });
```

This is my route.py code:

```
 @main.route('/process', methods=['GET','POST'])
def process():
    posts = Post.query.all()
    post_list = []
    for post in posts:
        if post.school_lat:
            lat_lng = f"{post.school_lat}, {post.school_lng}"
            post_list.append(lat_lng)
            for i in post_list:
                return jsonify({'data': post_list[i]})
```

Comment: Did you try sending the whole list instead of just the first item (because essentially you skip all the iterations except of the first due to `return`ing prematurely)? _After_ the `for post in posts:`'s body (not _within_ it) you simply do `return jsonify({'data': post_list})`.

Comment: @CherryDT Thankyou that worked!!!